# Placing return false

Tags: python

I am very new to coding, two weeks in.
So I do apologize if this is a very silly question.

I have been trying to complete the following codingbat problem:

Given an array of ints, return True if one of the first 4 elements in the array is a 9. The array length may be less than 4.

Why does the below code not return the correct answer?

```
def array_front9(nums):
  if len(nums)>4:
    count = 4
  else:
    count = len(nums)

  for i in range(0,count):
    if nums[i]==9:
      return True
    else:  
      return False
```

If the return False is placed on a new line and not in the loop it works.

Can someone please explain this to me.

Comment: We call them **lists** in Python, not "arrays".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first iteration of the loop, the loop checks if `nums[0]` is 9 and always returns either `True` or `False`; you're not giving any chance for the rest of the elements to be inspected. You should only return `True` if the element being inspected is 9, and return `False` only when this fails for the first four elements, i.e. outside the loop.

```py
def array_front9(nums):
    return 9 in nums[:4]
```

Comment: Just `9 in nums[:4]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    count = 4
    if len(nums)<4:
        count = len(nums)
    if 9 in nums[:count]:
        return True
    return False
```

**What's wrong with your code**

```
if nums[i]==9:
      return True
else:  
      return False
```

In above lines you're just checking for 1st value if it is 9 then it returns True else False

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is if the first number in your list is not 9 then the loop will stop and function execution will stop it's because of `return False` in else condition.

```py
def array_front9(nums):
  count = [len(nums), 4][len(nums) > 5]
  for i in range(count):
    if nums[i] == 9:
      return True
  return False
```